# Oracle : Wrong precision after update query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing a problem with he update query. I am updating the balance1 field to 6442450941.026600.

```
update account_subscriber set total_balance1=6442450941.026600
 where SUB_ID='xyz'
```

but the result is coming as below (after firing select stmt we get)

TOTAL_BALANCE1  6442450941.02659988

2nd scenario :
Lets update with the following value

```
update account_subscriber set total_balance1=6442450941.4567
 where SUB_ID='xyz'
```

The results is 6442450941.45670032.

Can you please help me in understanding why the precision is getting changed.

Sql*plus version is  version is 10.2.0.3.0

Thanks and Regards,
Chandra Bhushan Bakshi

Comment: don't use floating point to store money values!

Comment: something like NUMBERPS(10,2)  would be more appropriate

Comment: used the datatype as NUMBER(22,8).

Comment: You mention SQL*Plus-- does that imply that you are issuing the `UPDATE` and the `SELECT` from SQL*Plus?  Or are you using some sort of client application that is actually doing the `UPDATE`?  If your column is fixed precision as you say, rather than a `FLOAT`, the data will not be rounded if you execute both statements in SQL*Plus.  It seems more likely that there is a client application involved that is actually doing the `UPDATE`, the client application has a floating point variable where the value is stored, and the client application is losing the precision.

Answer (score 3):

The only explanation I can come up with is that somewhere in the path between your database and where it's being displayed it's being converted to a floating point value.  I use PL/SQL Developer for my Oracle development tool and consider it quite reliable.  So imagine my surprise when I ran the following:

```
create TABLE rpj_test (val number(22, 8));

INSERT INTO rpj_test(val) VALUES (6442450941.026600);

SELECT * FROM rpj_test;
```

and I got the exact results you reported (6442450941.02659968).  WTF?!?!?

But then I asked myself an important question - How can I test this to assure myself that the correct data is actually in the database?  So I ran the following query:

```
SELECT val * 10000 FROM rpj_test;
```

and got the answer I expected (64424509410266).

So it appears that the data in the database is correct.  No surprise there - I consider Oracle's NUMBER type to be one of the best unregarded feature of the product, it's been around forever, and it's ROCK SOLID (as it had better be if we want to have any chance of our systems working properly :-).  OK, so to my eye this looks like a floating-point conversion error - what can I do about that?  So off I went to poke around in PL/SQL Developer's Preferences configuration dialog, where I found a neat little setting titled "Number fields to_char" on the SQL Window tab, which was not checked.  I checked this, re-ran the first SELECT query, and lo and behold the data was presented as expected.

Morals of the story:

1. NUMBER computes and stores correctly.  If you think you've found a bug, think *really* **really** hard, over and over again.  Test it sixteen different ways.  Figure out HOW you can prove this isn't actually a bug.
2. The tools you use affect the results you get.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

You are supplying a value that cannot be resolved to the degree of precision you need by the data type of the receiving columm. If you require precision down to *millionths*, as the question implies, you should review the precision of the table field's datatype and adjust accordingly.

Comment: I won't pretend to be a big Oracle expert on internal datatypes, but I believe a number(x,y) is ultimately represented as a base-100 exponential, which means a value like 6442450941.0266 gets translated to something more like 6.4424509410266*100^(exponent), meaning that "trailing precision" is increasingly at risk for imprecise representation.

Comment: Could you please double-check that you're really using a Number(22,8) here? Doing some very quick scratchpad testing with that datatype and the values you've offered here and I do not see the same issue...?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using an imprecise data type.

Comment: What should be the correct datatype in this case to achieve the desired result?

Comment: That depends what the desired precision is. Some form of NUMBER (x,y)

Comment: datatype is number(22,8) in our case.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a pl/sql developer display issue.
In, PL/SQL developer, select Tools menu and Preferences options and in SQL window type and in Number layout uncheck the formatted options and select any other options and see the correct result. :)